# User based recommendation factoring in user data

Tags: recommender-system

The question is:
what algorithms (and libraries) should i use if i want to build a recommender system with the following data in mind representation:

```
USER_ID  ZIP  Movie1  Movie2  Movie3
1  2483  5  0  3
2  2483  4  1  5
3  2345  3  1  5
```

Basically i want to factor in user data into a recommendation of a movie.

(zips can be transformed to long/lat but thats another question and out of scope now)

i was searching the internet for hours with no success. So i will be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: How many data points do you have?

Comment: ~100,000
There will be more user data features at a later stage

Comment: I've answered, do let me know if you need any kind of example.

Comment: Try a [factorization machine](https://github.com/lyst/lightfm), and note that the user ID is not a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Collaborative Filtering:**

1. Match users to people with similar tastes –recommend what they like
2. Commonly used in e-retail
3. Avoids the issue of users only being recommended more of what they already like (allows serendipity)

Example:
Your Scenario.

Methods: Euclidean Distance, Cosine Distance, Pearson Correlation Coefficient (most common).

**Content-Based Recommendation**:

1. Match users directly to products and content
2. Recommend based on what you have bought or viewed in the past
3. Commonly used for document recommendation: webpages, news articles,
   blogs etc.

Examples:
Which Movie(s) might our user like?

*Option1*: The user selects preferences for the various features using pull-down menus etc. We match against the movies using Vector-Space methods (described next)

Methods: Vector-Space Method, K Nearest Neighbour(kNN)

*Option2*: The user rates a sample of the movies (explicitly or implicitly) as like/dislike. we then build a user profile model for that user using machine learning.

Method: Decision Trees

Comment: thanks for the answer, will collaborative filtering work for the scenario with user profile data (e.g. age, zip etc?) I was not able to find any examples in the web. (All are simple, only factoring in movie data)

Comment: You don’t need to use their demographics, you can you give their recommendation based on their taste, for example a new customer Cust-4 and he watched movie 1, 2 and gave 4,1 rating. So you suggest him movie3 as he is inline with Userid 2483. This is for your understanding.

Comment: The reason why i wanted to use demographics is to solve cold start problem (recommendation for a new user).

My assumption is that:
- having user profile + 3 choices (e.g. what are you interests) is more accurate than
- having just 3 choices

Comment: Yeah true, that would also be helpful

Comment: Can i use the same algorithms, or should i use something different for this if i want to use user profile data?

Comment: Yeah you can, it shouldn’t be an issue